# Differences between 2D hydrological modelling programs eg. HECRAS 5.0 (2D), TUFLOW, MIKE Flood

Tags: civil-engineering, hydrology

Just wondering what the difference is between 2D flood modelling programs. I am primarily considering whether HECRAS 5.0 (2D - currently in Beta) would be an acceptable alternative for simple 2D flood depth and velocity studies when compared to TUFLOW and MIKE Flood?

Answer (score 1):

The critical thing to be aware of is the suitability of application, and stability for that application. Noting that generally Finite Volume methods result in better accounting for volume hence mass balance errors are minimal.
Then whether it has shock capturing to track hydraulic jumps if modelling steeper catchments, and if it is capable of direct rainfall without instabilities and without mass balance. For example the ANUGA Hydro model is capable of all of these. HEC-RAS I believe is not capable of rainfall on grid as yet.